# How to convert an IP address to a string in python

Tags: python, sockets

This is my code

```
import socket
ip=56.90.89.78
ip2=str(IP)
M=socket.gethostbyaddr(ip2)
print (m)
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. `ip=56.90.89.78` is a syntax error in Python. Or are you asking about that? In Python, string literals are written using single or double quotes, so this could just be `ip = "56.90.89.78"` or `ip = '56.90.89.78'`

Comment: what does the capital IP in ip2=str(IP)  in reference to? Also ip=56.90.89.78 results in a syntax error, could you please provide more information

Answer (score 1):

You have to save your ip adress as a string and not a float or integer because it has multiple decimals. Also you need to be consistent with your upper and lower cases. Your code should be:

```
import socket 
ip = "56.90.89.78"
M = socket.gethostbyaddr(ip)
print(M)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to "convert" a literal IP address into a string, then like juanpa mentioned, it's just a matter of quoting in single or double quotes:

```
ip = "56.90.89.78"
```

If on the other hand, you want to resolve the IP address to a name, then you could indeed use the `socket.gethostbyaddr` function:

```
import socket
ip = "56.90.89.78"
name = socket.gethostbyaddr(ip)
print(name)
```